# How Can i jump my capsule collider with my humanoid character?

Tags: animation, character, collision-detection, collision, collider

Im moving my character with Vector 3 and i have attached an jump animation and also my character jumps amazingly but i want to jump over obstacles  animation works fine but  my collider is still on the ground? I also want to jump my collider with my character?? Please help me im stuck on this from 2 days

Comment: Could you add some code to make your issue easier to solve ? Thanks.

Comment: @Simon Long i dont know how to post my code here but i can explain to you im just using an Animator component and with an if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")){anim.SetTrigger("Jump")}; I am using a trigger function in animator and with its help im jumping character with animation but i also want the capsule collider to  jump with him im moving him using character controller  with Vector 3... please help me!!